# Failed to Open Stream /vendor/phpoffice/phppresenation/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php

Tags: php, symfony, autoload, phppresentation

Attempting to run an API with PHP PowerPoint generation by inclusion of a script with an auto loader pointing to my vendor directory under a custom /api/libraries/PhpPresentation directory results in a warning.

> Warning:
>   require(C:\wamp64\www\projectaim\api\libraries\PhpPresentation\vendor\phpoffice\phppresentation\vendor\composer/../symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\projectaim\api\libraries\PhpPresentation\vendor\phpoffice\phppresentation\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
>   on line 70

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: try to remove your vendor folder and reInstall it again by run `composer update`

Comment: Which vendor should I remove?  (See screenshot)

Comment: the root  one remove it

Comment: Changing to the parent (PhpPresentation) direcotry then deleting vendor and then running 'composer update' produced and generated the necessary downloaded files once more

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this. it requires php extension named "mbstring"

install PHP-mbstring extension on your server, if you are using M2 on local than run below CMD..

> sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring

change PHP version on above CMD acording to which u's using..
and restart you apache2.

let me know is it working for anyOne or not..  THANK YOU!

Comment: i have same issue with php spreadsheet